# Remainder operator with arc4random() and an array's count causes "could not find an overload" error

Tags: types, compiler-errors, swift

This code

```
    var randomNumber: Int = arc4random() % nameArray.count
```

gives me the error **"Could not find an overload for '%' that accepts the supplied arguments"**

I'm still trying to get used to the syntax and read the docs but can't seem to figure this one out. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to cast `arc4random()`'s return value (a `CInt`) to an `Int`:

```
var randomNumber: Int = Int(arc4random()) % nameArray.count
```

Comment: works great. I was doing this first and never thought of casting in front of the arc: arc4random() % nameArray.Count as Int

Answer (score 2):

have you tried casting the return value of `arc4random()` to an `Int`?

```
var randomNumber: Int = Int(arc4random()) % nameArray.count
```